# XPATH - get all <tag> text data except the last two <tag>

Tags: xpath

This is my HTML data

```
<book></book>
<book></book>
<book></book
....
....
'N' books
```

I'd like to get all the text data between all the `<book></book>` nodes except the last 2 `<book>` nodes

Basically i need `//book[1 to n-2]//text()`

Is there an XPATH query i can write for this?

Comment: Try something like `//book[1 <= position() && position() <= count(.)-2]//text()` (I did not try it out though...)

Answer (score 1):

One possible way to get all `book` elements within the same parent, *except the last two* `book` elements (in other words, *excluding the last and one before the last*) :

```
//book[position() < last()-1]
```

Comment: @wolfgang how about this one, doesn't it work for you?